# Using MAC address for encryption

Tags: pgp

I want to write a program that works only on computers with approved Mac addresses. 
I need 2 programs, program 1 takes the MAC address and pass phrase as input and generates a password.
Program 2 takes the password compares it with MAC address and generates the passphrase.
how would this be done?

Comment: What is an approved mac address?

Comment: Does the program "know" the approved MAC address (is it hard wired into the program)? Or does it "check against a database somewhere? Different requirements...

Comment: At which point is this about PGP? By they way, MAC addresses are very easy to fake in all common operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the MAC address as the salt for a hash of the pass phrase, you should be able to compare the result against a list of known hashes. That would seem to meet your needs. Do you need more help than this or are those terms you understand (or can google)?